# When was the first suggestion that Patrick Stewart should play Charles Xavier / Prof. X?

Tags: marvel, x-men, actors

In honor of the release of *Logan*, widely acknowledged most likely to be the [last time Patrick Stewart will play Professor X](http://collider.com/patrick-stewart-professor-x-logan/):

It strikes me as rather lucky that a bald English actor of the skill and gravitas of Patrick Stewart existed at the right time to play Charles Xavier, and one known in SF circles, to boot.   Most people would probably agree to the assessment of this as one of the most perfect and obvious castings in history.

Stewart, of course rose to prominence with the release of [*Star Trek: The Next Generation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation) in (1987-1994) and he first played Xavier in [X-Men (2000)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_(film)) 
That is a fairly long interval during which the rather obvious cast choice could have been discussed.

### What was the first coverage of the suggestion or evidence of discussions that Patrick Stewart should/would play Charles Xavier?

Since the idea was probably alive in fandom for a while before becoming a reality, a complete answer should cover weak sources (e.g. fan art, forums, blog posts) and (later) more reputable sources (e.g. Hollywood news coverage)

Comment: The earliest Usenet post I can find is [this one from October 1991](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rec.arts.comics/58u-xsOl-BI/kylOBUbNrJIJ) suggesting it.

Comment: My first exposure to the idea was the Star Trek/X-Men crossover novel [Planet X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_X_(Star_Trek)), from 1998. Plutor's suggestion is way earlier, though.

Comment: @Plutor, I love the way the poster even says *Prof. X:  Patrick Stewart (Anyone have any doubts on this one?)*

Comment: @Plutor That could probably be an answer. Unless someone comes up with some old magazine article or interview which suggests that it was thought of earler.

Comment: This is Patrick Stewart talking about when he first was asked about it http://www.rollingstone.com/movies/news/patrick-stewart-on-x-men-days-of-future-past-20140523

Comment: @Plutor feel like making that into an answer?

Comment: I wish I knew exactly which comic, but I remember reading a comic probably around 97 - 98 (the comic could be older), that had a fan question page, the question was something about which actors would play X-men characters and the answer mentioned Patrick Stewart as Xavier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that popular discussions of Patrick Stewart as Professor X started around the time of The Next Generation premiere in 1987. There's considerable overlap between the Star Trek and comic book fandoms. Before that, he was largely active in small parts and theatre (and movies based on classic plays).

## Oldest fan post I can find: October 1991

[This post in the rec.arts.comics](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rec.arts.comics/58u-xsOl-BI/kylOBUbNrJIJ) usenet group in October 1991 is the oldest reference I can find to casting Stewart as Charles Xavier. The parenthetical "Anyone have any doubts on this one?" perhaps suggests that this was a common dream casting already at this point.

## When Patrick Stewart learned of the idea: ~1997

In this [*Rolling Stone* interview](https://www.rollingstone.com/movies/movie-news/patrick-stewart-on-x-men-days-of-future-past-76458/), Patrick Stewart says that he first learned about the character (and that fans thought he would be perfect casting) was while recording ADR for a Richard Donner film. This was almost certainly [*Conspiracy Theory*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118883/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_97), released in late 1997.

## Oldest press references I can find: 1999

Apparently the [February 1999 issue of *Wizard* magazine](https://www.cbr.com/looking-back-at-wizard-90-february-1999/) included X-Men casting rumors, including Patrick Stewart, although none of the other ones ended up being correct.

[This page](http://www.teako170.com/profx.html) claims that the casting occurred on May 20, 1999 and was posted to startrekcontinuum.com on the following day.

This [*Variety* column](https://variety.com/1999/voices/columns/x-marks-the-scott-for-singer-helmed-fox-pic-1117503085/) from June about the casting of Dougray Scott as Wolverine is the first *press* reference I can find about his official casting (in the 4th paragraph). (Ironic aside: Dougray Scott obviously didn't play Logan, since *Mission: Impossible 2* filming ran long and he was injured while filming.)